# How much table overhead is too much?

Tags: mysql, overhead

I just saw in phpMyAdmin that one of our MySQL tables is 14MB in size, but has 10MB overhead. I'm guessing this is a lot!

How much is too much? Should I run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` regularly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Overhead" is not yet reclaimed space formerly occupied by now deleted records. If you're doing a lot of inserts / deletes, it's pretty much always going to be there. You can run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, but I wouldn't bother - especially on large tables (14M is not large, though) where it can take a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

To tidy up data table one can just use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name_here ORDER BY primary_key_here;
```

which could run faster than `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

This will de-fragment the data file. After extensive changes to a table, this may also improve performance of statements that use the table, sometimes significantly.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: how did you come to know about this?

Comment: Can't even remember, I think I was trying to solve the same problem as the quy who asked the question. Please check for yourself, but I am pretty sure it works.